# Breaking down an input from form into single letters, js?

Tags: javascript, html, text

I have been thinking about this for a while and didn't come up with anything by myself - So I was wondering if any of you had a clean idea on how to do it.

If a word were to be put into a textbox on a form and then submitted, I wondered if there could be some javascript which would break down the word into each letter, example:

"Eye" to "E" "y" "e"

is this possible?
could you spare some code? ^^

Comment: Did you want to include spaces?

Comment: What, precise, output do you expect? Your comment to Jeffman's answer suggests something other than what you show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var s = "Eye";
alert(s.split(''));
```

.split is normally used with a delimiter to split the string on, but if you pass an empty string in its place, it splits at every character.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EkDR5/).

Comment: This does not return `['e', 'y', 'e']` as the OP specified. It returns `['eye']` (at least in Chrome or Firefox, verified).

Comment: Explain my fiddle, then.

Comment: Your fiddle only appears to work because the default behavior of `alert()` is to show an array of non-complex objects as a comma separated list. I updated your fiddle and you can see this for yourself.

Comment: It almost does what i'd like - But it doesn't break them into separate variables. My plan was to input a word via form - and then for the letters to be brokendown so i would be able to edit/convert them separately. ^^'

Comment: @FeistyMango I think you are confusing the functionality of using split when passing an undefined delimiter or no delimiter at all vs. passing an empty string.